# Javascript Packing with many constraints, looking for a simple solution

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathematical-optimization, packing

This is not exactly packing as I can assign rectangle sizes myself, I just need a packed result.
I have rectangles of **same ratio** and different sizes 
FULL, 
HALF(area = 1/4 * FULL), 
QUARTER(area = 1/4 * HALF). 
All will be positioned horizontally only. The **container** is of width 3 times FULL and height will adjust to fit rectangles.

There will be 150 rectangles which will be given random sizes from array(full,half,quarter). Now I want to arrange these rectangles in the container so that there is no gap.

The container and rectangles are HTML DIVs. I am using JavaScript to pack them.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MywQ2/1/

In the above code I tried to constrain the selection of next box depending on present one.
May be i am not clear, i will try to explain again. I have 150 boxes, i just want to fill container with 150 boxes, they should be randomly of size full,half,quarter. We can also reject randomly selected size and get another one if it is found to create gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you either want something impossible or you formulate it wrong. If you pick your rectangles truly random, you will end up with gaps in your container.

In the sample code you have now you pick them semi-random, as it depends on the modulus of `status`.

If your goals is to fill the container with seemingly random rectangles, maybe next algorithm works for you (peude code):

```
for rectangle in ['large', 'medium', 'small']:
    try:
        place_rectangle_randomly_in_container(rectangle)
    except NoFreeSpace:
        if rectangle == 'small':
            # container filled
            break
```

where the place_rectangle_randomly_in_container tries to put the rectangle anywhere in the container at random.

To implement the placement, keep track of the container with a 2-dimensional array of booleans which indicate if that spot is still free; every element in the array represents the space a small rectangle would fill, so if the container can contain 12x12 small rectangles, that would be the dimension of the array. To check if a medium rectangle would fit at [2,3], you need to check the array for [2,3], [2,4], [3,3] and [3,4].

Placing the rectangles is then done by positioning them instead of floating them left.

Comment: May be i am not clear, i will try to explain again. I have 150 boxes, i just want to fill container with 150 boxes, they should be randomly of size full,half,quarter. We can also reject randomly selected size and get another one if it is found to create gap.

Comment: I checked your algorithm, but i don't think i want this much complexity of "putting rectangle anywhere in the container" I just want to fill the container from top left and spread sideways and downwards.

Comment: Well I don't think my proposed algorithm is that complex, it seems to suit your needs quite well:) Which part you think is complex? If you can come up with an easier algorithm, please share it with me as well

Comment: May be I dont understand your algorith quite well, sorry. Putting the rectangle anywhere in the container and checking if the area is already occupied seems difficult for me with javascript. Is there any possibility of tracking the new corner points available after checking and inserting rectangle. I am not sure if this works, and I have not added logic to check if overlap occurs. May be I should try some safe randomness so that they never overlap. I strongly appreciate your interest :) here is a new fiddle of our ideas http://jsfiddle.net/RXrcf/7/

Comment: I added some extra text about how to keep track of occupied space.

Comment: That is a great tip, I was trying out ways to implement that, I will implement the logic and update you. Thanks a lot for the support :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I implemented the idea of using a matrix to store vacant positions. But instead of spresding the problem over whole area, i took small portions and filled each one randomly. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8Cv/ Thank you so much for your awesome support :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out :) You could mark my reply as the answer if you want

Answer (score 1):

With the great help from Wesley I was able to find a decent solution to the problem. It exactly is not a packing solution but kind of a solution to produce seemingly random packed boxes without gap. Nothing like optimization was needed for me.

The solution was to divide canvas into 4x4 grids and fill each one 'seemingly random, using a matrix to keep track of vacant positions.

This example fiddle explains it well http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8Cv/ .

(Wesley's solution should be marked as answer, I am writing a separate solution only to help people coming to this page from Google, so have a look at his answer first)