# How can I create mosaic style image gallery of random and dynamic size images without using any plugins?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to create a simple mosaic style image gallery. I searched the web already and found so many people suggest to use available plugin. But I wonder is there any way so I can create mosaic layout image gallery myself? I want to fetch random and dynamic size images from the database and show in mosaic style.

Comment: Sure, look at the source of the plugin, that's how the author did it ...

Comment: I checked some JS source files but they used lots of function and advance techniques to do this. but i want to make it simple.

Comment: You are probably trying to implement some packing algorithm. Search for which one you want and implement the algorithm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891763/javascript-packing-with-many-constraints-looking-for-a-simple-solution  I remember myself doing this.

Comment: Thanks Sabithpocker. I saw ur question its not what exactly I want but might be it can help me to create my own code.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8891908/427146) by Wesley. Its said that *truly random* is either hard or impossible as it creates blank spaces and won't pack full.

If you want to see an implementation of the narrowed down version with only 3 predefined box sizes check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ua8Cv/)

Some code:

```
var FULL = {'height': 100, 'width': 200};
var HALF = {'height': 50, 'width': 100};
var QUARTER = {'height': 25, 'width': 50};
var sizes = ['quarter', 'half', 'full'];
var vacancy = [
  [1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ],
  [1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
  [1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
  [1 , 1 , 1 , 1]
];

for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  if ($('.grid.box.vacant').size() < 1) {
    var gridBox = $('<div class="grid box vacant"/>');
    $('.container').append(gridBox);
    vacancy = [
      [1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ],
      [1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
      [1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
      [1 , 1 , 1 , 1]
    ];
  }
  var className;
  var reduceChoice = 0;
  do {
    className = sizes[Math.floor(Math.random() * (sizes.length - reduceChoice))];
    var myPoint = findFreeGrid(vacancy, className);
    reduceChoice++;
  } while (!myPoint);
  markFill(vacancy, className, myPoint);
  jQuery(boxes[i]).addClass(className).css({'top': myPoint[1] * QUARTER.height, 'left': myPoint[0] * QUARTER.width});
  $('.grid.box.vacant').append(boxes[i]);
  if (noFreeGrid(vacancy)) {
    $('.grid.box.vacant').removeClass('vacant');
  }
}

function noFreeGrid(vacancy) {
  var nofree = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < vacancy.length; i++)
    for (var j = 0; j < vacancy[0].length; j++)
      if (vacancy[i][j] == 1) nofree = false;
  return nofree;
}

function findFreeGrid(vacancy, className) {
  for (var r = 0; r < 4; r++)
    for (var c = 0; c < 4; c++) {
      myPoint = [r, c];
      if (checkFit(vacancy, className, myPoint))return myPoint;
    }
  return false;
}

function checkFit(vacancy, size, position) {
  if (size == 'full') {
    for (var i = 0; i < vacancy.length; i++)
      for (var j = 0; j < vacancy[0].length; j++)
        if (vacancy[i][j] != 1) return false;
    return true;
  }
  else if (size == 'half' && position[0] < 3 && position[1] < 3) {
    if (vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] == 1
      && vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] == 1
      && vacancy[position[0] + 1][position[1]] == 1
      && vacancy[position[0]][position[1] + 1] == 1
      && vacancy[position[0] + 1][position[1] + 1] == 1
      )return true;
  }
  else if (size == 'quarter') {
    if (vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] == 1)return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function markFill(vacancy, size, position) {
  if (size == 'full') {
    for (var i = 0; i < vacancy.length; i++)
      for (var j = 0; j < vacancy[0].length; j++)
        vacancy[i][j] = 0;
  }
  else if (size == 'half') {
    vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] = 0;
    vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] = 0;
    vacancy[position[0] + 1][position[1]] = 0;
    vacancy[position[0]][position[1] + 1] = 0;
    vacancy[position[0] + 1][position[1] + 1] = 0;
  }
  else if (size == 'quarter') {
    vacancy[position[0]][position[1]] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for give me a good idea.